# Animate easing for scrollTop

Tags: javascript

How to animate easing for scrollTop? I'm using scrollTop to move div element when site is scrolled. I want div element to move smoothly not jumping so sharply.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 20 ) {
                    jQuery('.topBar').css({
                    'position':'fixed',
                    'top':-40,
                    'bottom':""
                });
   }
    else {
                    jQuery('.topBar').css({
                    'position':'fixed',
                    'top':0,
                    'bottom':""
                });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try animating the `topBar` tag then?

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        jQuery('.topBar').animate({
            top: "40"
        }, 300, function () {
            jQuery(this).addClass('scrolled');
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.topBar').animate({
            top: "0"
        }, 300, function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('scrolled');
        });
    }
});
```

I've created following fiddle to illustrate what i mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/2d3mxm5a/

Comment: It does not seem to work properly. Tried with this: `jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        jQuery('.topBar').animate({
            "top": "-40",
            "position":"fixed"
        }, 300, function () {
            jQuery(this).addClass('scrolled');
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.topBar').animate({
            "top": "0",
            "position":"fixed"
        }, 300, function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('scrolled');
        });
    }
});
` It takes couple seconds after scroll to move topBar div.

Comment: 1) your words were - "div element to move smoothly not jumping so sharply." - this is it; 2) could you show modifications in jsfiddle as well - it's easier to understand

Comment: And after I scroll to top of the page it does not anymore return toBar div to normal position as it did before.

Comment: In your jfiddle example it does exactly the same: after scrolling it takes few seconds to script to move div. Why? And to return div in up position it takes even longer.

Comment: Okey. By adding stop() it fixes the lag delay: jQuery('.topBar').stop().animate({..